# Excel open HTML file with FontAwesome

Tags: html, excel, font-awesome

Using Excel you can open up HTML files and if they containt TABLE tags these will be rendered correctly in XLS.

Now I have a TABLE and some cells have FontAwesome icons in them.
These will not show up in Excel.

In a normal Excel file I can use FontAwesome with no problem.
To achieve this I downloadeded FontAweseme and installed the FontAwesome.otf font.
Now when I select a cell in Excel, and I set the FontAwesome font, I can copy an icon from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/ and paste it into Excel and it will display correctly.

However, I want to achieve this by importing a HTML file into Excel...

HTML example file :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>world</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td><i class="fa fa-globe"></td>
      </tr>

  </body>
</html>
```

When you save put this in a file and save it as test.html, you can open it in your Browser and you will see the FontAwesome icon.
When save this as test.xls you can open it in Excel. All is rendered correctly in the correct cells, except the FontAwesome icon is missing. 
Anyone any idea on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I found it :-)

You have to use the unicode inside an i tag.
But you have to trigger the fontawesome css to work by using a class.
Now if you use a normal class like "fa fa-home" you will get the icon twice.
But if you just use "fa" as the class, the FontAwesome magic gets triggered and it works.

The following HTML will render correctly with a FontAwesome icon :-)

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>world</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>I am <i class="fa" style="color: red;">&#xf015;</i> a house !</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```